# asp.net url rewriting dynamically using httphandler/httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, httphandler, httpmodule

I have an asp.net application and I need to do the following:

Assume that i have a page called page1.aspx, what i need is that:

when the user requests page1.aspx?id=1 to be redirected to `http://myapp/books`

when the user requests page1.aspx?id=2 to be redirected to `http://myapp/movies`

books and movies are virtual paths and I don't want to do this using web.config (rewite section) since this should be dynamic.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Build an `HttpModule` and in `context_BeginRequest` you can get the current URL . Later conditionally redirect to the new URL.

```
public class RedirectionModule : IHttpModule
{
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      // get current url
      // conditionally redirect it
    }
}
```

[Edit] for SEO URL rewriting ASP.NET please refer [SEO URL rewriting ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599689/seo-url-rewriting-asp-net) page

Comment: i have done this the problem is in the RewritePath not working

Comment: can you explain, what happens when you redirect it.

Comment: When you run your final url (http : / / myapp/movies) directly will it shows valid result or gives some error ?

Comment: off course it will give an error, movies doesn't exist, i am trying to make friendly seo urls

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599689/seo-url-rewriting-asp-net